# Passing Array into Oracle .NET Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a .NET stored procedure and want to send it an array from database when calling it.
When I'm sending simple data like `String`, `DateTime` etc. it works very well.

The first method below is working but the second one is not... :(

```
namespace Smart
{
    public class Items
    {
        public static string Procedure1(string P_TEST)
        {
            return P_TEST.ToLower();
        }

        public static string Procedure2(string[] P_TEST)
        {
            return P_TEST.Length.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I expect `P_TEST` as a `string[]` type, my procedure doesn't show up in Deployment Wizard. So I am not able to deploy `Procedure2` to Oracle.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Oracle Deployment Wizard for .NET]

So how can I pass an array into my CLR procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many efforts I found that they do not support array binding as it is written [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28376/appendixa.htm#BEHJHHJG).

> PL\SQL Associative array is not supported.

So I'm joining and sending them as string.